# Angular 7.2.5 assign Subscription to EventEmitter fails error TS2740

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using ngx-translate with angular and have creaeted a Pipe based on the translation pipe.
Now I have updated from Angular 7.0 to 7.2.5 with TypeScript 3.2.4.
And the folowing code gives an error:

...

```
onTranslationChange: EventEmitter<TranslationChangeEvent>;


if (!this.onTranslationChange) {
      this.onTranslationChange = this.translate.onTranslationChange.subscribe((event: TranslationChangeEvent) => {
        if (this.lastKey && event.lang === this.translate.currentLang) {
          this.lastKey = null;
          this.updateValue(query);
        }
      });
    }
```

This is giving the error :

```
error TS2740: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'EventEmitter<TranslationChangeEvent>': __isAsync, emit, subscribe, observers, and 18 more.
```

Before my update everything worked fine.

Comment: these types are incompatible. is field onTranslationChange used for subscription from outside of the component?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use EventEmitter inside a pipe. These are solely used for the `@Ouput()` decorator on directives and components. Besides that, a `.subscribe` call, returns a `Subscription`. This is not an observable, but a subscription to an observable.

`EventEmitter` is something that extends Observable, so my guess is you want the code to be like this:

```
readonly onTranslationChange = this.translate.onTranslationChange.pipe(
  tap((event: TranslationChangeEvent) => {
    if (this.lastKey && event.lang === this.translate.currentLang) {
      this.lastKey = null;
      this.updateValue(query);
    }
  })
);
```

If this is not the case, and you just want to keep it a subscription, you should change it to this:

```
onTranslationChange: Subscription;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Basically I copied the translation pipe from the original code. So their should be changed something in the next release of it! https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/2c2679329643e2fb4eb7c6e8515b536387f6fefb/projects/ngx-translate/core/src/lib/translate.pipe.ts#L80

Comment: @Franki1986 absolutely right, in that case, you need to go for the bottom solution. You could post a pull request if you want to change it for them :)